# why does function relates input to only one output?

Tags: functions, definition

I'm trying to understand the rationale behind definition of function. Why is function defined as a relation which relates input to only 1 output?

What would happen if we allow function to relate input to multiple output?
Something like `y^2 + x^2 = 4`

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271613/why-is-a-function-defined-as-having-only-one-y-value-output

This link and the links in it should answer your query.